# "@csrf" "@error" "@enderror" and any thing that started with "@"visible in my website(laravel)

Tags: laravel

[page view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUWkA.png)

sorry if the code messed up im new, everytime i use "@csrf" in my code it keep showing in the website, my speculation is "@csrf" registered as a text, how do i solve this, thanks.

```
 <form method="post" action="{{route('login')}}">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
                        <p class="lead fw-normal mb-0 me-3"><strong>LOGIN</strong></p>

                    </div>
                    <!-- Email input -->
                    <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                        <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control form-control-lg @error('email') is-invalid @enderror"
                               placeholder="Enter a valid email address" name="email" autofocus required/>
                        @error('email')
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            {{$message}}
                        </div>
                        @enderror

                    </div>

                    <!-- Password input -->
                    <div class="form-outline mb-3">
                        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="password"
                               placeholder="Enter password" required/>

                    </div>

                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        <!-- Checkbox -->
                        <div class="form-check mb-0">
                            <input class="form-check-input me-2" type="checkbox" value="" id="form2Example3" />
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="form2Example3">
                                Remember me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#!" class="text-body">Forgot password?</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center text-lg-start mt-4 pt-2">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Login"
                                style="padding-left: 2.5rem; padding-right: 2.5rem;">
                        <p class="small fw-bold mt-2 pt-1 mb-0">Don't have an account? <a href="{{route('register')}}" class="link-danger">Register</a></p>
                    </div>

                </form>
```

Comment: Is your file a `.blade.php` file, or just a `.php` file? Those "blade directives" will only work for a `.blade.php` file; make sure you have the correct extension.

Comment: its .blade.php file